# Android - can't test subscriptions (only live mode enabled)

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I have a simple Subscribe button in my Fragment which I want to test for subscriptions (I'm using anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3). I tried testing in the simulator and nothing happens, the Billing Processor is not even initialized. No messages of any kind appear. If I try to test on my device, this:

```
bp.getSubscriptionTransactionDetails("my_id");
```

returns null and I get a message saying "This version is not configured for billing".

I read about this problem and found that I had to upload an alpha or beta.

This is a new version of an existing app. The old version didn't have subscriptions. I uploaded a version for Alpha testing. It includes the BILLING permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

and it currently appears in the Alpha track in the Console.

If I download the app from Closed Testing to my phone, the Subscription button does show the Subscription sheet, but with live options (meaning it's telling me I will be billed to my actual credit card).

The version name and version codes are the same in my current project and the signed bundle I uploaded (I haven't touched those numbers after uploading to the console so they are the same). The application id is the same.

I don't know what else to do.

How can I test the subscriptions on my local device with test card for success/failure?

This is the code on my sample screen (SubscriptionFragment), it features a single button:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subscription, container, false);

    subscribeBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.subscribeBtn);


    // Initialize
    bp = new BillingProcessor(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.play_console_license), this);
    bp.initialize();

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onBillingInitialized() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBillingInitialized: ");

    // Check if user is already subscribed
    subscriptionTransactionDetails = bp.getSubscriptionTransactionDetails("my_id");
    Log.d(TAG, "onBillingInitialized: " + subscriptionTransactionDetails);

    subscribeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (bp.isSubscriptionUpdateSupported()) {
                bp.subscribe(getActivity(), "my_id");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Subscription update is not supported.");
            }
        }
    });

    if (hasSubscription()) {
        // update UI
    }
}

private boolean hasSubscription() {
    if (subscriptionTransactionDetails != null) {
        return subscriptionTransactionDetails.purchaseInfo != null;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onProductPurchased: ");
}

@Override
public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPurchaseHistoryRestored: ");
}

@Override
public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBillingError: ");
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (bp != null) {
        bp.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If anyone else is struggling with this, you not only have to be a normal app tester, you need to go to Setup -> License testing and add your email there. Only then you will be able to test on your device locally.

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using is outdated, despite it's advertised 'v3 library', in fact it's 'v2 library' using old AIDL services which will be discontinued by Google in November.